# Unable to parse ICU expression. i18n using angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next, ngx-translate

I have array of left-menu items which I want to convert into other language.

below are my code:

**left-menu.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let m of menuItems; let last = last">
    <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of m.pages" [routerLink]="page?.link" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
     <mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined" style="padding-right: 10px;" [matBadge]="page?.alerts" matBadgePosition="after" matBadgeColor="warn" [matBadgeHidden]="this.linkText && showMenuBadge(page)">
        {{page?.icon}}
     </mat-icon>
     <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'" [matBadge]="page?.alerts" matBadgePosition="after" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgeOverlap="false" [matBadgeHidden]="false" [matBadgeHidden]="!this.linkText && showMenuBadge(page)" style="padding-left: 10px;" i18n="@@leftmenu">
        {page?.name, select, name {name}}
      </span>
    </a>
    <mat-divider *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
</ng-container>
```

**messages.hi-IN.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="leftmenu" datatype="html">
     <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, name {name}}</source>
     <target state="final">{VAR_SELECT, select, Talent {कार्रवाई} Dashboard {डैशबोर्ड} Address {Adresse} City {Ville} State {Etat} Occupation {Occupation}}</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I am getting following error here:

> Unable to parse ICU expression in "{VAR_SELECT, select, Talent
> {कार्रवाई} Dashboard {डैशबोर्ड} Address {Adresse} City {Ville} State
> {Etat} Occupation {Occupation}}" message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `other` option in `select` function:

```xml
     <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, name {name} other{}}</source>
     <target state="final">{VAR_SELECT, select, other{} Talent {कार्रवाई} Dashboard {डैशबोर्ड} Address {Adresse} City {Ville} State {Etat} Occupation {Occupation}}</target>
```